# PetaPoco not returning expected data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4, petapoco

I have a BIT data type on one of my columns.

I have written a query that does `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE BITCOLUMN <> @0`

It works fine if I pass in 1 or 0 but if I pass in 3 PetaPoco doesn't return the results I expect.

Executing the SQL in a query window does return all records when I use 3 as the parameter value.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: If I use `string SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE BITCOLUMN <> " + MethodParam;` This returns data as expected.

Comment: Please show the full code that executes this SQL.

Comment: What are you expecting when you use @0, 3 and what do you actually get?

Comment: I actually get the results for <> 1

Comment: I've tested this on both SQL Server and SQLite, and it returns the expected value. You'll have to show the code where you are actually calling this so that we can see if there is anything there.

Comment: I'm running against SQL CE 4 and PetaPoco 4.0.2

Answer (score 4):

Could you tell me what result you expecting? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx), A bit column can either be 1, 0 or null. It does not make senses to me when you pass 3 to it, since it will select all rows.

And my quick test shows that Petapoco behaves as expected.

```
using (var database = new Database("sql"))
{
    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBLTESTBIT WHERE BITCOLUMN <> " + "3";
    var test = database.ExecuteScalar<long>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBLTESTBIT WHERE BITCOLUMN <> @0", 3);
    var test2 = database.ExecuteScalar<long>(sql);

    Console.WriteLine(test == test2); // this output true
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: You mean something like `database.ExecuteScalar<long>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBLTESTBIT WHERE BITCOLUMN <> @0", "3");`? It won't work, you have to convert it to int first. Because the final sql is `SELECT * FROM tblTestBit where bitColumn<>'3';`

Comment: What version of PetaPoco are you running?

Comment: Change your sql variable to string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBLTESTBIT WHERE BITCOLUMN <> " + 3;

Comment: I am running the latest version from nuget with SQL Server 2008. It still works for me. You may have to post your petaPoco version, Sql server version and method you wrote here for people to have a look. Have you tried to debug it? It should show you what the last execute statement is.

Comment: I'm running against SQL CE 4 and PetaPoco 4.0.2

Comment: Maybe try to update PetaPoco if you don't have any customizations. Nuget allows you to easily fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be because when you use a parametrised sql string, you are passing in int with a value of 3 in as one of the args. PetaPoco will then create an IDataParameter for that argument and the DbType will be set to DbType.Int32 by default since PetaPoco has no idea what the underlying table column type is.

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem if it is an int. I assume directly querying the database does the same by converting it to an int

Comment: It depends what SQL Server does when it receives a parametrised query with a parameter value of an int which is being compared against a bit in the table.

Comment: Well it should behave the same way as when I query the database directly

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Sql()` not `Append`.

You should use `Query = new PetaPoco.Sql(` over `Query = PetaPoco.Sql.Append`